# localhost/~username/ not working

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

So i have stuck on this thing since last week . i am new to web development , and wanted to learn php , as soon as i started i had to setup apache server , for root directory it works fine but for localhost/~username/ it can't connect to server "localhost".
[image: error picture]

here are the files i had been messing up 
(sudo apachectl configtest : Syntax OK )

httpd-userdir.conf file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zmuc2jetpo3i0i/httpd-userdir.conf?dl=0

httpd.conf file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlrzqr95ge2qy3c/httpd.conf?dl=0

username.conf file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f13cgfgfb56esi7/mfaizanulhaq.conf?dl=0

(OS X el Capitan
10.11.5 (15F34)
&
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope no one faces this problem. In my case i had updated php to php 7 but in httpd.conf it was trying to load php 5 so by commenting out that line my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

If this is still relevant and you are fed up with trying to find a solution you can change Documents root folder to your user Sites folder. This will prevent everyone but you from accessing localhost from your machine, but it's a hotfix solution. I've had a deadline and I had to finish the site, so this worked for me.
Go to `httpd.conf` change

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
```

To look up your username in the terminal use `whoami`.

**NOTE:** Bear in mind you also need to change the following lines in `httpd.conf` it's located just below DocumentRoot within `<Directory>` tag you changed earlier.
Whatever it says in your file modify to this (that should be true for ALL configurations of the Apache2)

```
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

This is a really bad solution since your Users/username/Sites folder will be accessed directly when you type localhost in the browser, but when something goes wrong, or you've done something wrong this is the best solution so far especially if you are 100% certain you are not going to have more than 1 user access your localhost directory.

Comment: NO its not a issue for me any more . problem with me was that i had updated php to php 7 but in httpd.conf it was trying to load php 5 so by commenting out that line my problem was solved .